# Receiving temperature reading from arduino over bluetooth and display in android smartphone

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I have to do a project whereby I have to get a temperature reading from a temperature sensor and send it over Bluetooth to an android smartphone and display the reading.

I'm using MIT's app inventor to make the app. So far, I can connect to the Bluetooth module hooked up to an arduino uno r3 and I can display the temperature if I press the "display" button. I want the app to update the temperature reading itself without me having to press a button to update it everytime. How do I do this? This the code I have so far.

I've tried using the timer in app inventor to update the reading automatically, but the app inventor keeps crashing after it connects to the Bluetooth module.

The code blocks I have so far are in this link. http://www.flickr.com/photos/92242434@N07/8382878573/in/photostream

Answer (score 0):

Help me to understand about the requirement:

Why do you want to connect everytime? Does your phone be always near the temperature sensor?

What is the timer value you have set? I meant the period of interacting with the temp sensor?

just a pseudo:

for every 2 min
    if connected
         request temp
    else
         reconnect
         request temp

The problem with this code is, it will keep sending reconnect request , if you move out of range, thereby draining your phone's battery. you need to take a call, when actually you want to disconnect/ or y

Comment: I'm relatively new to this. The timer value is 1 second. I'll try changing the code to make it not connect every time. My phone doesn't have to be near the temperature sensor all the time.

Comment: does the crash happen first time during connect or is it the consecutive connect that is crashing..? Any logs that can be of help

Comment: The crash happens when i want to receive the temperature via bluetooth every second, it connects as expected, and the app is not requesting for reconnection everytime. I've separately tested the bluetooth connection part, it works well. When i use a button to get the temperature, it works as expected, the app crashes when i automate this using a timer. App inventor doesn't have a detailed log, it just shows whether the phone is connected or not. I don't think that would be much of help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the label that shows the temperaturature like this:

```
when Clock.Timer do:
 if (BluetoothClient.IsConnected) then:
    set Label.Text to: call BluetoothClient.ReceiveText
                  Number of bytes: call BluetoothClient.BytesAvailableToReceive
```

This video shows an example of what you are trying to do, with the App Inventor and Arduino codes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjtxrxVauZg